# Call bash-completion for another command from within completion function

Tags: bash, tab-completion

```
_example()
{
    local cur prev

    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"

    if [[ ${prev} == example ]] ; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "git" -- ${cur}) )
    elif [[ ${prev} == git ]] ; then
        _command
    elif [[ ${prev} == g ]] ; then
        # ??? TODO 
        # I want the same completion for `example git <TAB>` and `example g <TAB>`
    else
        COMPREPLY=()
    fi
    return 0
}
complete -F _example example
```

I know how to "call" bash-completion for next command. (code above)
eg.: `example git <TAB>` => completion for `git`

How to make bash-completion that "calls" any completion I want for next command?
eg.: `example g <TAB>` => completion for `git`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Populate `COMP_CWORD`, `COMP_WORDS`, and `COMP_LINE`, and then call `git`'s completion function `__git_wrap__git_main`.

For an example of populating `COMP_*` and invoking a pre-defined completion function, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48940230/1823664).

For more on figuring out how `git` completes, you [might want to start here](https://brbsix.github.io/2015/11/23/perform-tab-completion-for-aliases-in-bash/).

Comment: Yes, refer to second paragraph of answer and the link therein.