# How to reuse rostopic's completion function for completing a custom bash function?

Tags: ros, bash-completion

Defined bash function `rte()`:

```
$ function rte(){ rostopic echo $@ ; };
```

and attempted to use `rostopic`'s completion function

```
$ complete -p rostopic
complete -F _roscomplete_rostopic rostopic
```

via the command:

```
$ complete -F _roscomplete_rostopic rte
```

The above setting can be verified as follows:

```
$ complete -p rte
complete -F _roscomplete_rostopic rte
```

However, `rte <partial input><tab>` does not offer completions.

Question:  How to get `rte()` to use `rostopic`'s completion?  I guess when `rte()`'s completion calls `rostopic`'s completion, the context `echo` needs to be provided to `rostopic`'s completion (i.e., `COMP_WORDS` needs to contain `echo`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a solution -- now have the following in `.bashrc`:

```
function rte(){ rostopic echo "$@" ; };

complete -F _mycomplete_ rte

function _mycomplete_()
{
    local fragment=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    COMP_CWORD=2
    COMP_WORDS[0]="rostopic"
    COMP_WORDS[1]="echo"
    COMP_WORDS[2]=$fragment
    COMP_LINE="rostopic echo $fragment"

    _roscomplete_rostopic;
}
```